# Arithmentic operator(+) operator will check both return type and passing arguments or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class B;
class A {
private:
    int a,b;
public:
    A() {
        a=b=10;
    }
    void show() {
        cout<<"Hello of A: \n a:"<<a<<"  b:"<<b;
    }
friend  A operator+( A AA ,B BB) ;
friend  B operator+ ( B BB,A AA);
friend  B operator+( A AAA ,B BB) ; 
};
class B {
private:
    int c,d;
public:
    B() {
        c=d=20;
    }
    void show() {
        cout<<"\nHello of B: \n c:"<<c<<" d:"<<d;
    }
friend  A operator+ ( A AA,B BB);
friend  B operator+ ( B BB, A AA);
friend  B operator+( A AA ,B BB) ;
};
A operator+(A AA ,B BB) {
         A temp ;
         temp.a = AA.a + BB.c;
         temp.b = AA.b + BB.d; 
         return temp;
}
B operator+( B BB, A AA) {
        B temp;
        temp.c = AA.a+BB.c;
        temp.d = AA.b+BB.d;
        return temp;
} 

int main() {
class A aa;class B bb;
class A aa1 = aa + bb;
aa1.show();
class B bb1 = bb + aa;
bb1.show() ;
}
```

Hi I just tried this program and got compile Error as friend  A operator+ ( A AA,B BB); is being redefined again as friend  B operator+ ( A AA,B BB);
For my understanding overloading will check both return type and passing arguments.
But here I am not sure why I am getting compile time error flagging that , function redefinition  is done !!.
Can somebody help me !!

Below is the Error I got when I tried to run in unix terminal,

## CC overloading.cpp

"overloading.cpp", line 17: Error: operator+(A, B), returning B, was previously declared returning A.
"overloading.cpp", line 29: Error: operator+(A, B), returning A, was previously declared returning B.
"overloading.cpp", line 31: Error: operator+(A, B), returning B, was previously declared returning A.
"overloading.cpp", line 33: Error: operator+(A, B), returning A, was previously declared returning B.
"overloading.cpp", line 45: Error: Overloading ambiguity between "operator+(A, B)" and "operator+(A, B)".
5 Error(s) detected.
#

And How Can I use class B b2 = aa + bb; in the above code ?

Comment: The return type is not part of the function signature for function overloading. That's basic C++ knowledge, or at least it's supposed to be basic. I don't know what the errors you get are, but have you actually tried to *read* them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of a function does not participate in overload resolution. Only the function name and parameter list (and cv qualifiers for a member function) matter. But I can see no multiple *definition* in your code. The error is that you have re-declarations of the same function with different return types:

```
friend  A operator+( A AA ,B BB) ;
friend  B operator+( A AAA ,B BB) ; // same function, different return type!
```

Comment: @PrakashKumar, you are seeing error messages related to that -- two functions with same argument types but different return types are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the info.If I want to use below code , how it can be implimented ?    
    class A aa;  
    class B bb;
    class A aa1 = aa + bb;
    class B bb1 = aa + bb;